# Как использовать Html.DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Есть модель с заявками:

```
[Table("PotentialClients")]
public class PotentialClient : Person
{
    [Key]
    public int PotentialClientId { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string ThirdName { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    public string Sex { get; set; }

    public int PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    public int Pasport { get; set; }

    public int TypeOfSubscriptionId { get; set; }

    public string SubscriptionHead { get; set; }
```

Есть модель с существующими услугами:

```
 [Table("TypeOfSubscriptions")]
public class TypeOfSubscription
{
    [Key]
    public int TypeOfSubscriptionId { get; set; }

    public string SubscriptionName { get; set; }

    public int VisitQty { get; set; }

    public int SubscriptionCost { get; set; }
}
```

}

Как сделать, чтобы во View последнее для заполнения поле (SybscriptionType) было поле с выпадающем списком и предлагались все существующие варианты ??

Метод Create [get]:

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        PotentialClient potentialClient = new PotentialClient();
        List<TypeOfSubscription> LT = db.TypesOfSubscriptions.ToList<TypeOfSubscription>();
        ViewBag.LT = LT;

        var allTypes = db.TypesOfSubscriptions.ToList<TypeOfSubscription>();
        ViewBag.TypeOfSubscr = allTypes;
        return View();
    }
```

Метод Create [Post]:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "PotentialClientId,FirstName,LastName,ThirdName,DateOfBirth,Sex,PhoneNumber,Pasport,SubscriptionHead")] PotentialClient potentialClient)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.PotentialClients.Add(potentialClient);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Прописываю во View:

```
<div>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.TypeOfSubscriptionId, new SelectList(ViewBag.LT, "TypeOfSubscriptionId", "SubscriptionName"), new { @class = "form-control", @id = "repeatForPosition" })
</div>
```

На данный момент View выглядит так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На данный момент есть такая реализация во View:

```
 <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SubscriptionHead, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SubscriptionHead, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SubscriptionHead, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
```

Как вместо Label использовать DropDownList ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например получаем показываемый список (у меня словарь, т к название отличается от значение в `option`. (Вы можете передать его из контроллера). Вытянул со своего проекта... у вас вместо `Rules` будет    `SubscriptionType`.

```
// Все типы
@{
    Dictionary<string, string> Rules = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
{ "", null},
{ "По количеству товара", Discount.Content.RuleTypeAmount },
{ "По сумме товара или сумме скидки", Discount.Content.RuleTypeSum },
{ "Процент от суммы товара", Discount.Content.RuleTypePercent },
{ "По цене со скидкой", Discount.Content.RuleTypePrice }
};
}

 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Rule, new SelectList(Rules , "Value", "Key"), new { @class = "form-control", @id = "repeatForPosition" })
```

Comment: выдаёт ошибку: System.ArgumentNullException: "Значение не может быть неопределенным.
        Имя параметра: items". На форме отображается выпадающий список, а при присвоении эта ошибка.

Comment: @andreygrek значит у вас items пустой

Comment: ,я не понимаю что это означает. В форме создалось поле со списком, в котором перечислены все необходимые элементы. При сохранении выдаётся эта ошибка. Обновил исходный текст вопроса. Посмотрите, пожалуйста, я действительно не могу понять что не так.

Comment: @AndreyGrek запустите в дебаг режиме, он по идее у вас застопиться на ошибке, и посмотрите почему у вас переменная пустая..